# Cordova error with ionic : Unable to load Platform API from... Cannot find module 'properties-parser'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I wanted to get the device model into my ionic v5 app.

I wanted to use Cordova for that purpose running the following `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device`, but I did get the following error.

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-device': Error: Unable to load Platform API from C:\Users\my-project\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:
Cannot find module 'properties-parser'
```

Did somebody already had this error and find a solution to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, find a workaround.

Somehow, while trying to add the `cordova-plugin-device` cordova did try to use stuff inside the `platforms` folder.

To fix the problem, I had to remove them using ionic `cordova platform rm android` then I could run the command again and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First remove platform android with

```
sudo ionic cordova platform rm android
```

then add your plugin again

```
sudo ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-advanced-http
```

this works for me